# how to optimize build in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation, multiprocessing

How to expedite/optimize compilation of a huge project on Linux on a multi processor machine so that compilation is done in parallel utilizing all processors.

Any suggestions regarding special flags , tweaks would be helpful.

Regards,-J

Comment: `make -j`?  But note that build systems are often IO-bound, not CPU-bound.

Comment: Simplest answer is 'make -j x' where x is the number of cores. Without more information it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Also think about using ccache.

Comment: Be careful: make -j can get a bit greedy and take your system down if you don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have a *huge* project, say several million lines of C++, and a couple thousand CPUs to throw at it, you might want to look at how Google [solves](http://google-engtools.blogspot.com/2011/05/welcome-to-google-engineering-tools.html) its [build](http://google-engtools.blogspot.com/2011/06/build-in-cloud-accessing-source-code.html) problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
make -j <NUM_CPUS>
```

(See `make(1)`.)

Comment: I'd add `-s` as well so you get quieter output.  I've noticed a significant improvement just on medium sized projects.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the build system you use.  If it's GNU `make`, simply adding `-j` (or `--jobs`) should parallelize the build.  It may or may not work on a *huge* project, depending on how well-behaved the makefile is.

See also [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should setup dependency rule and tell the compiler to emit them(-MD -MP for gcc), for example:

```
YOUR_DEP    :=$(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(YOUR_OBJ))
-include $(YOUR_DEP)
...

%_c.o: %.c Makefile
@echo [GCC ] $<
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MD -MP $< -o $@
%_cpp.o: %.cpp Makefile
@echo [CXX ] $<
@$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MD -MP $< -o $@
```

This way make can do the dependency checking. However, parallel make -j sometime cause trouble for huge project with multiple level of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distcc tool to perform compilation of different source files on different Linux machines from a predefined machines-pool. Obviously "-j" in the make command line must be used.
Additionally you should try to avoid recursive Makefiles, i.e. invoking "make -C $sub_dir" recursive from Makefile - this slows make process on huge projects.